# Is there a simple way to embed a MathJax formula to webpage?

Tags: mathjax

If MathJax can export formula as image, I can use  to insert it to a webpage easily. Unfortunately, current MathJax don't support to export image! :(

Is there a simple way to create a embeded code to show formula just like Twitter above? If you have, could you show me some sample codes? Thanks!

< href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"  data-count="horizontal" data-via="my">Tweet
< script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js">

Answer (score 1):

See [my response](http://groups.google.com/group/mathjax-users/msg/0ee02e60be3ce55d) to this question on the MathJax user's forum.

> MathJax does not have image creation capabilities, and I don't know of a way to
>   make that possible from Javascript (a quick web search suggests it is not readily doable).
>   If you are looking to convert TeX to images, there are plenty of tools for doing that
>   already.  You could, for example, use TeX with dvipng, or one of the tools designed for
>   that like the LaTeX Equation Editor or Laeqed applications.  There are a number of
>   on-line tools for doing this as well.

Answer (score 1):

This question is already kinda old. But was searching for something like this myself. Apparently there are some Tex Rendering Services Available.

Take a look at this Answer:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53436/implement-an-api-call-to-display-latex-as-inline-image

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" async  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    $$e = mc^2$$
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/16h1hjot

Comment: This does not produce the the equations as images (it is using the CommnHTML output, not an image format), and gives you no way to export them as images.)  So it doesn't answer the question.